# netbeans supress or disable system dynamic

Tags: linux, debian, netbeans

while document has been already saved and I press ctrl+s - system dynamic "beep". it infuriates colleagues =(. How to disable it? Maybe it is possible to disable dynamic system-wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a hardware level (really high pitched) beep, [you can turn it off](http://www.arsgeek.com/2006/08/23/how-to-turn-off-the-annoying-system-beep-in-linux-debianubuntu/).

All you have to do is go into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` and add the line `blacklist pcspkr`. This should prevent the kernel from loading the module that enables the hardware level beep.

If this doesn't work, find your desktop environment's startup file, and add the line `xset -s` to it, which should turn off Xorg's beep.